# Unable to retrieve ajax post data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to `jquery`, I learn this from other site, I'm trying to receive the post values from the `ajax` but it doesn't receive anything. Here is my code:-

**index.html**

```
<form id="refresh_form" name="refresh_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="minlat" id="minlat" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="minlong" id="minlong" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="maxlat" id="maxlat" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="maxlong" id="maxlong" value="1">
    <button id="refreshbutton" onclick="callAPI();">Refresh</button>
</form>

<script>
function callAPI() {
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'getData.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $("#refresh_form").serialize(),
        //data: postForm,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            // Display a map on the page.  Obviously this needs to be done only once.
            if (firstTimeLoaded == false) {
                firstTimeLoaded = true;
                mapOptions = {
                    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
                map.setTilt(45);

            }
            initialize(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

**getData.php**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['minlat'])){
    $data = $_REQUEST['minlat'];

    echo json_decode($data);
    exit;
}
```

Any reason why it didn't work? From my console, I see this data is being sent.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKDtl.png)

[image]

Comment: in getDATA.php check what you are receiving with print_r($_REQUEST); die();

Comment: any reason to use `contentType: false,` ??

Comment: @SalvadorP. Nothing.... I just don't understand why.

Comment: echo json_decode($data,true);

Comment: @devpro no reason, I just follow the guide from the website.

Comment: Like @devpro comment the cache, contentyType and processData variables maybe they are giving problems.

Comment: in your example no need to use `cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,`

Comment: Content type is specifying the content type of the request, putting it to none may give problems.

Comment: @NickyMan  didn't you get the correct code?

Answer (score 1):

You code looks fine, please test on server side $_POST variable is filled up or not

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
die();
```

Check it in response of network tab in browser's inspect.

If still not working then check .htaccess fil,  **Check in your .htaccess file for redirect rule** is written or not. if redirect rule is there then remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use that

```
if(isset($_POST['minlat'])){
    $data = $_POST['minlat'];

    echo json_decode($data);
    exit;
}
```

Since its `type: 'POST'`

Comment: I'm not sure that's the problem, $_REQUEST contains the content of $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE.

Comment: Sure but why do you want to json_decode $_REQUEST ['minlat'] ?

Comment: this is not an issue.

Comment: echo json_decode($data); return null so maybe its the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure as I haven't checked it yet, but try this one:

```
function callAPI() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'getData.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {"minlat":$("#refresh_form").serialize()},
    //data: postForm,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        // Display a map on the page.  Obviously this needs to be done only once.
        if (firstTimeLoaded == false) {
            firstTimeLoaded = true;
            mapOptions = {
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
            map.setTilt(45);

        }
        initialize(data);
    }
});
}
```